# Call function of child in parent pointer vector

Tags: c++, oop, stdvector

I am trying to make a vector of Child and Parent objects. I have a function foo() in Child class which overrides foo() in Parent, and prints No instead of Yes. However, when I call the foo() function of all objects in the vector the parent foo() function is run for the child object. Is there a way to have all children objects in the vector to run the overridden function while parent objects run the parent function?

To extend the question can that also be done for multiple classes which extend the Parent class and override the foo() function.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Parent {
  public:
    Parent () {
      cout << "New Parent" << endl;
    }
    void foo() {
      cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
  public:
    Child(): Parent() {
      cout << "New Child" << endl;
    }
    void foo() {
      cout << "No" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> v;

    v.push_back(std::make_unique<Parent>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<Child>());


    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i){
      (*i)->foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
New Parent
New Parent
New Child

Yes
Yes
```

The output i would like is:

```
New Parent
New Parent
New Child

Yes
No
```

Comment: Vo[ting to close as a typo.  You forgot to make `foo` `virtual` in `Parent`

Comment: Unrelated: Classes designed for runtime inheritance should always have a `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 1):

`foo()` needs to be declared as `virtual` in `Parent` in order for `Child` (and other descendants) to override it.

`Parent` should also have a `virtual` destructor, as well, so that descendant destructors are called correctly when `delete` is called on a `Parent*` pointer (such as by `std::unique_ptr<Parent>`).

Try this:

```cpp
class Parent {
  public:
    Parent () {
      cout << "New Parent" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Parent () {}

    virtual void foo() {
      cout << "Yes" << endl;
    }
};
```